# Driver igb_uio.ko is missing and is needed for openvswitch --dpdk

Tags: drivers, network-bridge

I am following the instructions in https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/DPDK.html to install the DPDK version of OpenVswitch on Ubuntu 16.04.  After the installation I cannot find the ***igb_uio.ko*** kernel module.   The ***uio_pci_generic*** is available but I believe the ***igb_uio*** driver would be better for the 82599 NICs I am using.

I can't find an apt package in the repository to get this.  Can anyone tell me where to get it?

**UPDATE** Based on [Christian](https://askubuntu.com/users/532139/christian-ehrhardt)'s input below the path I followed to get to a working configuration was to basically build DPDK 16.07 and OVS from scratch.  There are a number of things different in both DPDK and OVS from the versions that exist in the Ubuntu 16.04 library, some of which I note here that will hopefully spare someone else the time to learn this:

- **ovs-vswitchd** no longer looks at the --dpdk command line option.   Instead you enable dpdk through setting an option in the data base via **ovs-vsctl**. look at the ova documentation carefully for **other_config:dpdk-init=true**
- Contrary to documentation the discovery of DPDK devices is not enumerated in the log files.
- The DPDK utilities (python scripts mostly) have been renamed to **dpdk-**.  Specifically **dpdk-bind** is the utility that is used claim specific devices for DPDK use.
- The OVS **make install** process will install **ovs-vswitch** in **/usr/local/sbin**. (Other components similar.)  The typical Ubuntu deb packages will install to **/usr/sbin**.
- DPDK makes uses of **hugepages** which is not well documented.

Keep in mind the above information will probably age quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the kernel drivers were added on the following release of Yakkety which includes DPDK 16.07. For an example package see [dpdk-igb-uio-dkms](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/yakkety/+package/dpdk-igb-uio-dkms).

If you need that for Ubuntu Xenial you would have to rely on a ppa build or maybe more helpful use the [Ubuntu Cloud Archive](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/CloudArchive) which will likely contain the DPDK as in Yakkety once released.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I notice that the setup is a bit different in 16.07 and the utilities have been renamed.

Comment: Oh yes it is - I wonder if I should blog about it or push something to the ubuntu serverguide about it. TL;DR is look at http://openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-vswitchd.conf.db.5.html and move everything you had as commandline for DPDK into those options.

Comment: `dpdk-igb-uio-dkms` package contains source code of `igb_uio` kernel module. Should I compile the source code inside this package after installing it?

Comment: No, just install that package, it builds itself via DKMS.